# Mimicking AJAX file uploads in webbrowser control is failing

Tags: c#, javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8, webbrowser-control

I am having a problem but I am not sure where.

I have created a website which uses Angular, this might not be pertinent but then again it might be. Of the many features of this site one of them is the ability to upload a file and then get back a response. The response is a simple amount of JSON. The only browser I have to get this working with at this point in time in IE8. *avoiding incoming thrown objects* - I have tried everything to change this fact, but it is what it is.

I have gotten the site to mimic AJAX uploads by submitting a form and having the response redirected to an iframe. In fact I am using a module that does most of this for me.
So far all this works better than you would believe in IE8. I know right? Unbelievable!

But… there’s always a but…

I need to get this page working when running in a Webbrowser control in a winforms project. I get as far as uploading the file which happens successfully. My REST service gets it, saves it, and returns the correct response. When debugging I can even see that the response is available. But for some reason the load method for the iframe is never called. The iframe which I have made visible on the page is never populated with the JSON.

Again this works when running in IE but not when in the webbrowser control. I get no errors and have breakpoints and debugger statements everywhere. It’s like the response falls in a crack and is ignored.

Would anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening? *crossing fingers*

Comment: It would really help if you could post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay I have been ..., well there is no adjective for how busy I have been.

The answer lied in the module that was chosen to help upload files. It worked for IE 8 straight up, but not when running in the web browser control. The module was dynamically binding an onload event to an iFrame which was also being dynamically create to handle the post back. Anyone that has worked with IE and needed to upload files might know of this method. This worked in IE8 but not in the web browser control. We modified it to add the onload event when the iFrame is created and that fixed the issue.